# How to test AngularJS directives

Tags: angularjs, testing, angularjs-directive

I am working on a Rails 3.2 app that will be using AngularJS. I can get Angular to do what I need, but I am having a very difficult time figuring out how to test what I'm doing. I am using guard-jasmine to run Jasmine specs using PhantomJS.

Here is the (relevant) html:

```
<html id="ng-app" ng-app="app">
  <div id="directive-element" class="directive-element">
  </div>
</html>
```

The javascript (in coffeescript) looks like:

```
window.Project =
  App: angular.module('app', [])
  Directive: {}

Project.Directive.DirectiveElement =
  ->
    restrict: 'C'
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
      element.html 'hello world'
Project.App.directive 'directiveElement', Project.Directive.DirectiveElement
```

The code above does exactly what it is intended to do. The tests are the problem. I can't get them to work at all. This is one thing I had tried. Posting this is mostly just to start the conversation somewhere.

```
describe 'App.Directive.DirectiveElement', ->
  it 'updates directive-element', ->
    inject ($compile, $rootScope) ->
      element = $compile('<div id="app" ng-app="app"><div id="directive'element" class="directive-element"></div></div>')
      expect(element.text()).toEqual('hello world')
```

As an aside, I am new to AngularJS, so if there are any best practices regarding namespacing, modules, etc. that I am not following, guidance would be appreciated.

How do I get a test for this to work?

Answer (score 69):

[Here's how alert directive is tested in angular-ui/bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/alert/test/alert.spec.js).

[Here's another simple set of tests, for the buttons directive.](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/buttons/test/buttons.spec.js)

Here are a few tips:

- Be sure to tell the test runner what module you are testing with `beforeEach(module('myModule'))`.
- If you have external templateUrls in your directives, you'll want to somehow pre-cache them for the test runner.  The test runner can't asynchronously `GET` templates.  In bootstrap, we inject the templates into the javascript with a build step, and make each template a module.  We use `grunt-html2js` grunt task.
- In your tests, use the `inject` helper in a `beforeEach` to inject $compile and $rootScope and any other services you'll need.  Use `var myScope = $rootScope.$new()` to create a fresh scope for each test.  You can do `var myElement = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')(myScope);` to create an instance of your directive, and have access to its element.
- If a directive creates its own scope and you want to test against it, you can get access to that directive's scope by doing `var directiveScope = myElement.children().scope()` - It will get the element's child (the directive itself), and get the scope for that.
- For testing timeouts, you can use `$timeout.flush()` to end all pending timeouts.
- For testing promises, remember that when you resolve a promise, it will **not** call its `then` callbacks until the next digest.  So in tests you have to do this a lot: `deferred.resolve(); scope.$apply();`.

You can find tests for directives of varying complexity in [the bootstrap repo](http://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/).  Just look in `src/{directiveName}/test/`.

Comment: Given plunker does not seem to work anymore, do you have a working version? The documentation on testing directives with Jasmine for AngularJS is super bad and hurting for an example like the one at the  plunker.

Comment: are you sure about myElement.children().scope()? I does not work for me =(

-> UPD: I had to do $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 12):

[Angular Test Patterns](https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-test-patterns) may help you, there are examples in both coffeescript and javascript.

Here's a testing pattern to verify the [example directive](https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-test-patterns/blob/master/example/coffeescript/app.coffee#L76) is [rendering the expected output](https://github.com/daniellmb/angular-test-patterns/blob/master/patterns/directive.md#render-the-expected-output-).