# How do I test user interface widgets?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs

In angular, and in javascript in general, how to unit test action like, clicking a button should show dialog box, clicking the same button when the box is shown hides the box. My question is how to test elements dom attributes ? In GWT a pattern design called MVP ( Model View Controller ). Where The controller is tests but, not the view !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has already been answered here to some degree: [How to test behavior in the link function of a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406491/how-to-test-behavior-in-the-link-function-of-a-directive)

Angular's test suite of choice is [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/). Basically what you need to do, in angular is `$compile` your directive, then use `browserTrigger()` to interact with the DOM elements it produces however you need to, then test the outcomes in your $scope.

Angular is 100% BUILT WITH TESTABILITY IN MIND.  Products like Selenium shouldn't be necessary.

If you need more examples. I highly recommend just hopping into [Angular's Git repository](https://github.com/angular/angular.js), and [looking at their directive tests](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/test/ng/directive).

Answer (score 2):

You can use some front end testing suites such as [cucumber](http://cukes.info/) or [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to write front end test suites to check browser behavior. You can then set up the test suites to also run on multiple browsers to have a solid platform for dom testing.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this approach when it comes to Angular applications. This is a fine approach for legacy applications that aren't built with testability in mind, but with an Angular application this sort of test suite shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Vojta Jina (a member of the AngularJS team) has some great notes and example code on this: https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing