# AngularJS - Testing a directive's link function, how to spy on controller

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

If I have directive like this

JS:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  this.someMethod = function() {
  };
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: true
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
      controller.someMethod();
    }
    controller: 'MyController',
  }
});
```

I want to create a Jasmine spy to ensure that the link function called `controller.someMethod`, but this will not work:

Spec:

```
var elem = angular.element('<div my-directive></div>');
var scope = $rootScope.new();
$compile(elem)(scope);

var ctrl = elem.controller('myDirective');
spyOn(ctrl, 'someFunc').andCallThrough();
```

The spy is created too late, because the controller was instantiated and the link function called in the `$compile` statement.

What other ways are there for spying on something that happens in the link function?  Is it possible to maybe instantiate the controller before hand and pass it into `$compile`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406491/how-to-test-behavior-in-the-link-function-of-a-directive suggests testing the resulting state, but the state that I am trying to test is not a DOM state.  The controller saves the result of the method call and puts it into an array to keep track of the reference, but the reference is not identifiable, so I can only count the length of the array, which seems less than ideal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [AngularJS Developer Guide's page on Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> Best Practice: use **controller** when you want to expose an API to other directives. **Otherwise use link**.

I would suggest creating a service for whatever `someMethod()` does. Then you can mock and spy on that service. Otherwise you may have to look for some other sign that what you wanted to happen has actually happened.

Comment: I think this is probably correct.  I've learned since asking this question that the structure of your program between controllers, directives, and services is really important for testability.