# Jasmine test a function inside a link of a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, hyperlink, jasmine

How to test a function inside a link of a directive in angular?

```
link:function(scope,element,attr) {
          var closeBox = function(event) {
            //do something...
          }
            $(document).on("click",closeBox);
        }
```

How to test "closeBox"?

Comment: i think that you must mock it

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş - can you share any document where i can mock, specifically for this problem? btw, mock what?

Comment: mock the function, http://plnkr.co/edit/qXqitB5MO3T4hshYL4Pw?p=info - this link is for mocking a service but you can try to implement it for your case

Comment: also you can check out this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406491/how-to-test-behavior-in-the-link-function-of-a-directive